# @Qualifier and Dependency Inversion Principle

Tags: refactoring, solid

I recently discovered SOLID principles and i'm trying to learn how to properly apply them. I have an application that had a huge interface:

```
public interface NotificationService {
  public void sendNewProjectRequestNotificationToDesigners(String projectId);
  public void sendNewProjectAcceptedNotificationToCustomer(String projectId);
  public void sendNewProjectRejectedNotificationToCustomer(String projectId);
  ...
  // and aboud 30 more methods like that
  // specifying the type of notification and who is going to be sent to
}
```

This clearly violates:

- SRP: so many different kind of notifications
- OCP: Every new notification i just modified the class
- ISP: In every single class that injects a NotificationService, will only want 1 of all the methods.
- DIP: The clients of this class need to be aware of the exact method to use.

so i began my refactoring and came up with:

```
public interface NotificationSender {
  public void sendNotification(String projectId);
}

public class NewProjectRequestNotificationSender implements NotificationSender {
  public void sendNotification(String projectId) {
    ...
  }
}

// and many other classes, one for each method in the original interface
```

Now to apply Dependency Injection, i declared each class that implements NotificationSender as a @Bean with a qualifier name.

And the classes that require a specific notification sender, the dependency is injected with @Qualifier.

Question 1: By having to use @Qualifier in the clases that require a specific NotificationSender, hence these clases are still forced to know details like the qualifier name of the given NotificationSender, am i still violating Dependency Inversion Principle?

Question 2: Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the qualifiers are just a hint to your dependency injection system. They're more configuration than code. You are still accessing the beans only though the `NotificationSender` interface, so your code doesn't know any more about the implementation details of the different instances.

Imagine you were unit testing a bean that used a qualified `NotificationSender` injection. You could pass it any `NotificationSender` you liked (a mock, perhaps). Outside the DI framework, your code couldn't care less what implementation you give it!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could add another layer of indirection by using a factory and injecting the concrete classes into the factory, then injecting the factory where you need the concrete classes.  The factory could have a method to which the caller is passed, and then the factory could figure out what to return based on that.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting idea, i'll give it a try and then post my results as soon as i can.

Comment: Every issue can be solved by adding another layer of indirection... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering What's wrong with having the class who needs the sender require the interface of said sender in it's constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered refactoring your interface to something like:

```
public interface NotificationSender {
  public void sendNotification(NotificationEvent event);
}

public final class NotificationEvent {
    private final NotificationKind type;
    private final String projectId;

    ...
}

public enum NotificationKind {
    REQUESTED, ACCEPTED, REJECTED, ...;
}
```

Comment: Yes i have, and i discarded it because, there were 30+ type of notifications, and having such enum, was potentially leading to really big switch/if-else statements in some cases, the first time i had to write a switch, really noticed the code smell.